# Convert vertical table to horizontal in python(Flattening the table)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, pivot

[image]

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(“data.csv”)

pd.pivot_table(df, index = ‘Employee ID’ , values = [ ‘ Member ID’, ‘Firstname’, ‘Lastname’] , aggfunc =‘first)
```

The format seems to work but only for one value , how do i display everthing ?

Any help is appreciated .

Comment: Some more info would help. Are you talking about a csv file? Do you already have code to read it to a python dictionary and write it back to the sheet?

Comment: Yes it is a csv file ,  i am having issues with flattening the data to the format mentioned above. No i do not have that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_index()` and `unstack()`, but you will need to fix the columns, e.g.:

```
In []:
df = pd.read_csv(“data.csv”)

df['ID'] = df['MemberID']   # Copy because you want it in the values too
df = df.set_index(['EmployeeID', 'MemberID']).unstack(level=1, fill_value='').sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: 'Member{}{}'.format(x[1], x[0]))
print(df)

Out[]:
          Member1ID Member1Lastname Member1firstname Member2ID Member2Lastname Member2firstname Member3ID Member3Lastname Member3firstname 
EmployeeID                                                                                                   
1                  1             Ann              Anu         2             Ann              Aju        3             vAnn              Abi 
2                  1            John             Cini         2            John             Biju             
3                  1           Peter           Mathew         2           Peter           Joseph
```

But I feel you can simplify if you really don't need MemberID in the values (you have it in the column name) or if you don't mind a `MultiIndex` then:

```
In []:
df.set_index(['EmployeeID', 'MemberID']).unstack(level=1, fill_value='').swaplevel(axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

Out[]:
MemberID          1                  2                  3          
           Lastname firstname Lastname firstname Lastname firstname
EmployeeID                                                         
1               Ann       Anu      Ann       Aju      Ann       Abi
2              John      Cini     John      Biju                   
3             Peter    Mathew    Peter    Joseph
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_table` of pandas

```py
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Employe-id'], 
                    columns=['MemberID','firstname','lastname'])
```

To install pandas use `pip install pandas`
then first make a dataframe object by `read_csv()`
then use above method to convert